# Automating the game stick hero

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pixel

I'm currently trying to automate the game stick hero. I've already worked out how to calculate the distance between the player and the next platform but I'm not sure how to program the "bridge". The bridge is just a stick thats getting bigger the longer I click or press on the screen. With various measurements I figured out that the growth of that stick is not linear and changes over time. Theoretically I could do measurements for every possible case, but that would be over 400 measurements I need to make. So I thought there has to be a better way to do this. I've already done a few measurements:

- 300ms - 167px
- 400ms - 226px
- 500ms - 275px
- 600ms - 334px
- 700ms - 384px
- 800ms - 462px

So basically I have the number in pixels, and I need to calculate the required time with a non linear "growth" function in python.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a math question than a Python question.  I googled "generate a polynomial from points" and came up with this handy tool:

http://www.xuru.org/rt/PR.asp

which suggests this function as a very close approximation for the six data points you have:

> y = 7.916668533·10-11 x^5 - 2.141667182·10-7 x^4 + 2.265417219·10-4 x^3 -
>   1.168583619·10-1 x^2 + 29.86667374 x - 2850.000654